# Wordpress redirection error with woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm developing a e-shop using wordpress and woocommerce. The shop should only be shown to members, except the product that is the membership. For this i'm using the following code:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'logged_in_only' );
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'membership_only',1,1);
function logged_in_only() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        if( !is_page( 20 ) && !is_page( 110 ) && !is_page( 35 ))
           auth_redirect();}
}
function membership_only() {
    if (!is_product(207)){
       wp_safe_redirect('website',301);
}
}
```

The part of logged_in_only works like a charm. But the membership_only only redirect when trying to access common pages, if you try to access another product it opens. In the "!is_product(207)" I already tried putting 'product name', 'product id' and how it is in this code, and always happens the same.

Comment: I assume product ID 207 is the membership product. Non-members should have access to product ID 207 alone and for members all other products right?

Comment: Exact. I'm using the woocommerce to sell the membership, so they need to access this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'restrict_products_pages' );
function restrict_products_pages() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { //add allowed pages & products here
        if( !is_page( 20 ) && !is_page( 110 ) && !is_page( 35 ) && !is_product(8))
           auth_redirect();
   }
   else { //add non-allowed pages & products here with ||
       if (is_product(8)) {
           wp_safe_redirect('website',301);
           exit;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Updated the code in original answer, check and let me know.

Comment: Then I got redirection loop... But i found where was the error, the theme was sending the header before the function got called. So I used the solution found on https://tommcfarlin.com/wp_redirect-headers-already-sent/ . But I really appreciate your help